# Ruby on Rails & Ajax - How to specify what javascript is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my rails app I have a page with multiple remote forms and ajax triggers on it. There's a comment form, a "retweetesque" button, and paginated infinite scrolling. The problem is, when I submit a comment or "retweet" something, the pagination code gets called also, causing a duplicate list of items to append because the page is the same. How can I specify what js is called for each ajax call?

"Retweet" Form

```
<div>
    <%= form_for(@book, :remote => true, id: "add-book-form") do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :title, value: book.title %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :product_url, value: book.product_url %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_url, value: book.image_url %>
  <% end %>
  <button class="book-card-add-book"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

application.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.book-card-add-book', function(){
  $(this).siblings('#new_book').submit();
  $(this).addClass('book-added');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height()-$(window).height() - 50) {
        $('.pagination').text('Please wait....');
        return $.getScript(url);
    } 
  });
  return $(window).scroll();
  }
});
```

dash.js.erb

```
$('.book-list').append('<%= j render( :partial => "books/books") %>');
$('.book-list-cover').load(function(){
    $('.book-list').masonry('reloadItems');
    $('.book-list').masonry( 'layout' );
});

$('.book-card-comment-form-container').hide();
$('.book-card-overlay').hide();
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript will_paginate(@books) %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.one](https://api.jquery.com/one/) is pretty usefull for creating one-off event handlers, you can combine this with a check where you look if your pagination has already been populated.

The first part is to abstract out the part where the pagination is populated to become a generalized piece of functionality:

```
# application.js
$('.pagination').one('paginate', function(event, data){

    var $self = $(this);

    // adjust this selector according to your needs
    if ( ! $self.children('li' ).length ) {
        $self.replaceWith(data);
    }
});
```

Then [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) populating the pagination from your ajax script:

```
# dash.js.erb
$('.pagination').trigger('paginate', ['<%= escape_javascript will_paginate(@books) %>']);
```

Comment: Also you really SHOULD not be loading data or really doing anything on `$(window).scroll` since the event fires repeatedly while the user is scrolling. Its a real performance killer.